# Download ePub (NSURLConnection), save it, and open it with UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: objective-c

So I am trying to download an ePub book with NSURLConnection. So far, the download is working perfectly. The issue comes when I try to save it and open it. When I try to open it with UIDocumentInteractionController, the app crashes saying that the directory is null.

Here is my code:

```
 //Download ePub file
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.terceiroanjo.com/materiais/missaopiloto.epub"];
 NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:10.0];
 connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

then

```
// save it ("data" = NSMutableData that was appended from the received data of the download)
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
     NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u/%@", NSDocumentDirectory,@"missaopiloto.epub"];
     [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

and to open the ePub:

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"missaopiloto" ofType:@"epub"];
 NSURL *urls = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

 self.documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:urls];
 documentController.delegate = self;

 [documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

When I try to open it, the app crashes:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

I get it, the directory is nill, but why? What am I doing wrong. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that, once you download and save a file, it's not becoming part of the bundle.

If you want to access the file you must provide the local path and create the local URL

```
NSString  *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u/%@", NSDocumentDirectory,@"missaopiloto.epub"];
NSURL *urls = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

self.documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:urls];
documentController.delegate = self;

[documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
```